# Oracle find whether a corresponding record exists within a number of days

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am trying to subtract to date from each other

The question says that I have to create a query to display the orders that were not shipped within 30 days of ordering.

Here is my trying:

```
select orderno 
from orders 
where 30> (select datediff(dd,s.ship_date,o.odate ) 
           from o.orders,s.shipment);
```

The error I get is

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

These are the two tables :

```
SQL> desc orders

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

ORDERNO                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
ODATE                                     NOT NULL DATE
CUSTNO                                             NUMBER(3)
ORD_AMT                                            NUMBER(5)

SQL> desc shipment
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

ORDERNO                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
WAREHOUSENO                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
SHIP_DATE                                          DATE
```

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax with an Oracle database.  Apart from the logic errors in the SQL, you code simply cannot run on Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method, using Oracle syntax:

```
select o.orderno
from orders o
where 30 > (select o.date - s.ship_date
            from shipment s
            where s.orderno = o.orderno
           );
```

Note the correlation clause in the subquery, but each table is only mentioned once.

The problem that you have is that an order could ship on more than on occasion -- and this would generate an error in the query, because the subquery would return more than  one row.  One solution is aggregation.  You need to decide if the question is "the entire order does not ship within 30 days" or "no part of the order ships within 30 days".  The latter would use `MIN()`:

```
select o.orderno
from orders o
where (select MIN(o.date - s.ship_date)
       from shipment s
       where s.orderno = o.orderno
      ) > 30;
```

Comment: I thought about the "entire order" problem, but I don't think the data model as described encompasses that. If part of an order had shipped within 30 days but the other part had not shipped at all then there would be no information on that in this data model, and the queries would all look as if the order is complete.

Comment: @DavidAldridge . . .  If there are multiple ship dates per order, then the use of a subquery with `>` will generate an error.

Comment: indeed. It's obviously a simple example, where only one shipment is probably expected. Best if the query is robust against such stuff though.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be wanting something along the lines of:

```
select ...
from   orders o
where  not exists (
         select null
         from   shipments s
         where  s.orderno   = o.orderno
         and    s.ship_date <= (o.odate + 30))
```

Date arithmetic is pretty easy if you just want a difference in days, as you can add or subtract days as integers. If it were months, quarters or years you'd want to use Add_Months().

Also, it's better in the query above to say "shipment_date <= (order_date + 30)" rather than "(shipment_date - order_date) <= 30)" as it lets indexes be used on the join key and shipment date combined. In practice you'd probably want an index on (s.orderno, s.ship_date) so that the shipment table does not have to be accessed for this query.

I used NOT EXISTS here because in the case that there might be multiple shipments per order you would want the query stop finding additional shipments if it has found a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is wrong and you are trying to do a cross join implicitely. I think what you need is an INNER JOIN which i assume is going to return one row (if it returns multiple rows then use >ALL) like:

```
select orderno 
from orders 
where 30> (select s.ship_date - o.odate 
           from orders o INNER JOIN shipment s
           ON o.orderNo = s.orderNo);
```

Comment: I think the query as it stands still doesn't work, because there is no correlation between the main query and the subquery. I think it would return a "too many rows" error because the subquery is returning the unfiltered projection of the join between orders and shipments.

Comment: Yeah that should be it.. We should not join but use corelated query something like:  `select o.orderno
from orders o
where 30 > (select o.date - s.ship_date
            from shipment s
            where s.orderno = o.orderno
           );` I just tried to correct in terms of OP's join or syntax..